# echo not displaying text in a wordpress widget

Tags: php, wordpress

So I am trying to make a WordPress widget that echoes out the movie input. I've put the echo in line 10 of the widget function however it doesn't echo out the input. Now I know I could swap this out to echo `$instance['movie'];` , however I want to test that my `movie_search` method works, which it isn't. Any help is appreciated and sorry if this answer is really stupid I am still quite new to coding.

```
<?php  
public function widget( $args, $instance) {

    echo $args['before_widget']; 
    if (!empty( $instance['tmdbapikey'] ) ) {
        echo $args['before_tmdbapikey'].apply_filters(  
                'widget_tmdbapikey', 
                $instance['tmdbapikey']
            ).$args['after_tmdbapikey'];
    }

    //widget content output
    echo $movie_query;

    // whatever you want to display after widget (<div>, etc)
    echo $args['after_widget']; 
}

public function form( $instance ) {
    $tmdbapikey = !empty( $instance['tmdbapikey'] ) 
            ? $instance['tmdbapikey'] 
            : esc_html__( '', 'mpd_domain' );
```

```
<p>   
    <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('movie')); ?>">
        <?php esc_attr_e('movie:', 'mpd_domain'); ?>
    </label> 

    <input
        class="widefat" 
        id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'movie' ) ); ?>"
        name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'movie' ) ); ?>" 
        type="text" 
        value="<?php echo esc_attr( $movie ); ?>">
</p>
```

This is the method for saving inputted user string.

```
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
    $instance = array();

    $instance['tmdbapikey'] = (!empty($new_instance['tmdbapikey']))
            ? sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['tmdbapikey'] ) 
            : '';

    $instance['movie'] = (!empty($new_instance['movie'])) 
            ? sanitize_text_field($new_instance['movie']) 
            : '';

    $instance['size'] = (!empty( $new_instance['size'])) 
            ? sanitize_text_field($new_instance['size']) 
            : '';

    $instance['description'] = (!empty( $new_instance['description']))
            ? sanitize_text_field($new_instance['description']) 
            : '';

    return $instance;
}
```

Movie search method

```
public function movie_search(){
    //copies inputted data to movie variable
    $movie_query = $instance['movie'];
}
```

Comment: Obvious error is obvious? You are **not** echoing movie search, but variable, which is possibly empty. Try adding `$movie_query = movie_search();` before `echo $movie_query;`

Comment: Thanks for the help yeah I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to pass the `$instance` into the `$movie_search` method. So the line should have been `public function movie_search($instance)` as the variable was not a global variable like I originally thought it was, leaving it an empty variable. Also needed to add a `return $movie_search` to the last line of the movie search method.

Hence I had to change line 10 to `echo $this->movie_search($instance)`.

Comment: Also a solution. I am glad you solved it. Great job!

Comment: Thanks, also just wondering since I am quite new to PHP what would recommend is the best way to learn it.

Comment: For me it was trial and error, loads of (preferred search engine) queries and so many swear words yelled at my non functioning code :)

Comment: Haha, that sounds similar to what I do too.